# Why does this Stream.take/2 call break a functioning Stream?

Tags: elixir, xmerl

I have the following function, which parses an XML document:

```
defp stream_parse!(dict) do
  dict
  |> SweetXml.stream_tags!(:entry)
  |> Stream.map(fn {:entry, doc} ->
    doc
    |> SweetXml.xpath(
      ~x".",
      id: ~x"./id/text()"s,
      definition: [
        ~x"./definition"l,
        gloss: ~x"./gloss/text()" |> transform_by(&List.to_string/1),
        origin: ~x"./origin/text()"sl,
        refs: ~x"./refs/text()"sl
      ]
    )
  end)
end
```

Here, `new_dict` is a binary representation of a verified XML document. The following code runs and completes successfully, and it displays hundreds of thousands of entries, the entire collection, via the call to `IO.inspect/1`:

```
new_dict
|> stream_parse!()
|> Stream.each(&IO.inspect/1)
|> Stream.run()
```

Here, there is only one change, namely the call to `Stream.take/2`. Yet, this results in the program hanging after displaying the following Xmerl error: `[error] 2781- fatal: :error_scanning_entity_ref`

```
new_dict
|> stream_parse!()
|> Stream.take(100)
|> Stream.each(&IO.inspect/1)
|> Stream.run()
```

Why does the call to `Stream.take/2` break this process?

Comment: please provide the full stacktrace of the error

Comment: There is no stack trace. The program simply halts and displays this error alone. It is strange.

Comment: are you taking the stacktrace from localhost or from some reporting system? stacktraces in elixir tend to use multilines so you might not get the full stacktrace on some basic filtering rules.

Comment: it's from localhost. there's no stacktrace because the program is hanging, not exiting with an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bang in the name of the function `stream_tags!/2` already gives a hint it might raise.

Now, looking into [the code](https://github.com/kbrw/sweet_xml/blob/v0.7.3/lib/sweet_xml.ex#L400) of `SweetXml`, we might see that it [spawns processes and monitors them](https://github.com/kbrw/sweet_xml/blob/v0.7.3/lib/sweet_xml.ex#L516) inside [`Stream.resource/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Stream.html#resource/3) with calls to `:xmerl_scan.string/2`, raising upon any issue *and* even upon unexpected [process termination](https://github.com/kbrw/sweet_xml/blob/v0.7.3/lib/sweet_xml.ex#L522) (your case.)

My wild guess would be that premature stream termination results in halting these processes and hence you see the error raised from the `after` clause of this `Stream.resource/3`. There is nothing to add in a SO answer here, I’d suggest either dig into it deeper and provide a pull request to `SweetXml` once you use it, or at least report an issue to there bug tracker.